# How to use Visual Studio 2012 to retrieve username and password from Microsoft Access

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Hello World I am a novice programmer with Visual Net. I started a project where I would like to use an Acess DB to store username and passwords and then subsequently use this to login into the app. Can some plse help with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Beside the fact that this task is possibly very bad for a novice I would like to say that storing sensible data like passwords safely is not a trivial task and cannot be simply done, you have to be aware of implications of security, encryption and cryptography to do this right. While this task is fine for learning often such learning code creeps later into some piece of production code with introducing nasty side effects. Check keepass.info to see a tool that is fully able to handle encryption to realize what the complexity of such a tool is. Also:  http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Samuel is there a general outline then on how to about this sensibly usin visual studio?

Comment: Well you are currently mixing concepts as it is not clear what you want to achieve anyway. When you are new to something you should concentrate on one problem domain. If you are learning basic (which I would not suggest when C# is available anyway) then you should concentrate on basic features. Otherwise you are mixing database access, communication with database and your language up. I would suggest you getting a book for the language first and understand the basics

Comment: @Samuel. Ok. My problem domain is this. I created a table in Access with username and password fields. Then a simple login form with visual studio. I now want my app to connect to the DB and look up the username and password in the table and either allow login access or not

Comment: I would search forms authentication... there are many tutorials on this and it will create the table and allow all sorts of extra features.